# Rounding issue in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I've continued trying different variations of number_format and float on a certain column in my blade template, but no matter what I still end up with numbers like 514.238054 instead of 514.24

I'm currently using this format:

```
{{ (number_format((float)$item['test']['category'], 2, '.', '')/number_format((float)$item['new']['category'], 2, '.', ''))*100 }}
```

Is there another method I can try with this that would keep it down to two decimal places properly?

Comment: its the result you should format, not the divident or the devisor

Comment: Be very careful doing any arithmetic on floating-point numbers. I strongly suggest using a library to handle this for you. Something like https://github.com/moneyphp/money has been tested well.

Comment: Having code like this in your view is fairly ugly. You should define an accessor on the model and do the math there, or at least put it in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the result you should format, not the dividend or the divisor.

So if anything it should look something like this

```
{{(number_format(((float)$item['test']['category']/(float)$item['new']['category']), 2, '.', '')) * 100}}
```

Comment: That makes sense now, I plugged this in and it worked perfectly, thanks! I'll make sure to only format the result from now on

Answer (score -2):

**This Php Code Works Just Fine For Above Explained Task!
I've Tried It On My Php Ide!**

**Actual Code:**

```
$flo= 514.238054;

echo number_format((float)$flo, 2, '.', '');
```

**Ide Screenshot Before Execution:**

[Before Execution Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF0IT.png)

**Output Ide Screenshot:**

[After Executing The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npjk8.png)

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING.

Comment: This doesn't really help the OP because they had the syntax right but were doing an additional calculation which produced another float.

Comment: noone is questioning that it works, but you're not contributing anything new to the topic, it's the order of things that is creating undesired effects. Not how he uses the function